# exit 1 is necessary appending to 'else'

Tags: bash

I am following an instruction on control flow commands,
in which `exit 1` is appended to each `else`,  for example

```
    #! ~/bin/bash
    min_val=1
    max_val=100
    int=50
    if [[ "$int" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        if [[ "$int" -ge "$min_val" &&  "$int" -le "$max_val" ]]; then
            echo "$int is within $min_val to $max_val."
        else
            echo "$int is out of range."
        fi
    else
        echo "int is not an integer." >&2
        exit 1 # here,
    fi
```

I run and get its exit status

```
    $ bash test_integer2.sh
    int is not an integer.
    $ echo $?
    1
```

However, when I comment out the `exit 1`, the exit status is still 1.

```
  ...
    else
        echo "int is not an integer." >&2
        #exit 1
    fi
```

Is it a proposed practice to keep `exit 1`?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce on osx with bash 4.4. If I comment `exit 1`, the exit code becomes 0.

Comment: Oh, and just 1 question : does your current code returns `int is not an integer` or only when you replace `int=abc` ?

Comment: ty, I find the flaw. I run it on another file which unchanged. @Aserre

Comment: As an aside - did you really mean `#! ~/bin/bash`, or is the `~` a typo?  (Clue: your kernel won't expand it the way your shell does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a shell command failed it always return exit status as `1`. In your case it failed `if` condition which is also considered as success or not. As it was failed so exit status is `1`.

Now answering to your question

> Is it a proposed practice to keep exit 1?

Answer is, its depend if final execution is successful and outcome is as expected your will `exit 0` else it should be `1` or the number returns from the command which is larger than `0`. Suppose in else part you are again executing some other commands what will you do definitely you will return a exit status based on the final outcome of your script. Hence managing `exit status` is always a good practice.

Comment: `$?` returns the exit status of the last command executed, in this case the status of `echo "$int is out of range."`, which has exit code of 0. try `false || echo ok; echo $?` to see it for yourself.

Comment: `always return exit status as 1` is incorrect here, it could vary depending upon the implementation. Rephrase it

Comment: @Inian, I have corrected my answer based on your advice.

Comment: "*If a shell command failed it always return exit status as 1.*" Not true, a command can return anything it likes between 0-255, non-zero indicates an error by convention.  `grep` for example, returns 1 if the match is not found and 2 if the file is not found.  bash itself can return 126, 127, or 128+N, see `EXIT STATUS` in `man bash`.

Comment: @cdarke, You are true. I have modified my answer based on your comment. Thanks